# Does a list of "interesting" questions belong into a tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

The [Haskell tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info) contains a list of "Interesting questions/answers":

> ### Interesting questions/answers
>
> - [What is a monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad)
> - [Why are side-effects modeled as monads in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488646/why-are-side-effects-modeled-as-monads-in-haskell)
> - [foldl versus foldr behavior with infinite lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082324/foldl-versus-foldr-behavior-with-infinite-lists/3085516#3085516)
> - [...]

A question or post being "interesting" is very subjective. The system automatically provides [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell?filter=all&sort=linked) [lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell?sort=votes) for questions and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[haskell]%20is%3Aanswer) that reflect the opinion/the upvotes of users.

Other languages provide FAQs (Java, [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq)) instead. However, frequently answered questions like [What is the monomorphism restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32496864/1139697) ([duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/32496864?lq=1)) are completely missing in the list.

In my opinion that list should get removed from the tag wiki, since it's growing step by step, isn't ordered by any means, makes most of the tag wiki blue, and there aren't any factors that need to be fulfilled for a question to be added.

So, does a list of "interesting" questions (not FAQ!) belong into a tag wiki? Or should we get rid of it?

Comment: The tag wiki already covers the justification.  Quote: "To avoid answering the same questions over and over again, please check the list of interesting questions".  Very reasonable.   If you don't like the value judgement then just change it to "common".

Answer (score 4):

We need *a* place to organize commonly asked questions and duplicate targets. The closest, most relevant place for this is the tag wiki.

So unless there's another place to store them, or another way to organize them, I'd say the tag wiki is just fine.